# Illustrator CC2017 stroke weight 0 pt

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, cc-2017

I'm an architect and I use Illustrator as a tool to set line weight before print or site publish. I have a small, but annoying problem: a lot of my cad drawing have 0pt line weight and apparently illustrator cc2017 doesn't recognize them anymore. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

here's how the original PDF appears in Acrobat reader:
[image]
here's how the original PDF appears in Illustrator CC2017:
[image]
here are the lines of the original PDF selected to show the lines are there:
[image]

Comment: Your cad probably issues a hairline instruction with 0. But for illustrator 0 is 0 and illustrator has no hairline instruction. Which in your case is really dangerous since hirlines print the thinnest line the printer can make but setting a value is possibly under this value.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously things have developed to more consistent. Zero stays as zero. Unfortunately that's against established CAD and printing practices.

As a workaround do this:

Select one of those ghost lines. Then goto Select > Same > Stroke weight. Give some color and thickness.

Answer (score 0):

I also see you're having trouble with fills - the diagonal crosshatch typically indicating (at least here in the US) insulation is not coming across - you may have to select one of the fill entities which is doubtless there behind the linework and see if there is a pattern fill which has been generated, and if so, adjust its appearance, or if not, pick the relevant pattern fill and apply, then save that as a graphic style and bulk apply it to all the insulation sections. You can, with one of these selected, open the Appearance Palette and make further edits, and save this as a new graphic style, OR over-ride the existing definition and update all the current elements with this style in the drawing. I use this approach to manage consistency of lineweights and other such items when retouching architectural drawings with Illustrator.

To get the right crosshatches available to you, open the Swatch Libraries>Patterns>Basic Graphics Lines, and you should find one that's perfect for rigid insulation:
[image]

As an example of using the appearance palette, I duplicated the fill on the object, and added a colour fill above, set to a blending mode of "colour burn" to add a blue behind the linework of the rigid insulation.
[image]

Hope this helps; j'espère que ça vous aidera.

Si vous avez besoin d'autres examples, veuillez suivre ce lien: [arch-grfx.solutions](https://www.arch-grfx.solutions)